# Confusing conversion occurring while loading Parquet into Snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Parquet table on S3 that I'm trying to load into a Snowflake table with a single `variant` column, and then select the fields of this variant column into a table with many columns.

This Parquet table has a field called `full_latency`; it is an int32.  I can confirm this by inspecting any of the Parquet files, or by querying the same table in Redshift.  E.g., using the `pqrs` tool, I see this:

```
...
...
full_latency: 18123
...
```

And I can use the same tool to show the schema of the Parquet file, and confirm `full_latency` to be of type int32.

When I load it into Snowflake, however, this value is converted to some sort of duration type:

```
select v:full_latency
from my_table
limit 1

Row V:FULL_LATENCY
1   "00:00:18"
```

There are many int64 columns that are not being changed to whatever format this is.  My copy command is extremely simple:

```
copy into my_table
from @my_table/dt=20211023/
pattern='.*/.*/.*/.*';
```

My question: why is this happening and how can I make it not happen?

Comment: What happens if you do a `select v:full_latency::int`?  I assume it errors?

Comment: @MikeWalton Surprisingly, it does not error.  But it turns `00:00:18` into 18, for instance.  The original column is in milliseconds.

Comment: It looks like Snowflake is interpreting the field to be a time in milliseconds, but is truncating it to seconds and retaining the additional information.  I would open a Support ticket with Snowflake and have them look into what is happening behind the scenes for you.

Comment: this implies the type of the column is time related, if you cast it to `::number(32,4)` instead of `::INT` do you get the 3dp of sub-second value, thus `SELECT ((v:full_latency::float)*1000)::int` might give you your full precision